# Mac Pro, my displays don't work after waking up from sleep. Troubleshoot?

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting

I've confirmed on another computer that my monitor works.  The DVI cable works.
My Mac Pro does successfully boot up (I hear the start-up chime, as well as the Gmail "new email" notification chime).

But I can't get an actual screen to show up on my monitor.

I have two video cards (ATI Radeons, Apple issued.  4 DVI slots total).  I've tried each slot.  No dice.

Any troubleshooting suggestions?

My setup was working just fine when I last put my computer to sleep.  Stopped working when I woke it up.

Comment: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2098705&tstart=0

Comment: which 2 video cards are you using?

Comment: ATI Radeons.  I took out one of them, moved the other to an unused slot.  Still no display.  Is it really possible that both of them burned out?

Comment: Are they both apple versions of radeon cards?

Comment: Yes.  Original hardware.  I haven't changed anything since I bought the computer.

Comment: What displays are connected?

Comment: Dell 2407wfp (wide screen monitor).  Only display.

Answer (score 1):

Went down to the Mac repair store.

Turns out **both** my ATI Radeon video cards had burned out.  (Power surge, perhaps?)
Getting a new card fixed the problem.